# htaccess file, cache, and site speed

Tags: .htaccess, caching, pagespeed

In my default **.htaccess file** are the following lines :

```
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
```

1- **What does mean : access plus** ?

2-**What happens if I change**  :

- ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
- to
- ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 6 months"

3-In case I change one jpeg image on the site, **what image will see a visitor who visited the site within the last 2 weeks** :

- the previous image ?
- the new image ?

4-Of course **I wonder the same thing for css and javascript changes**.

**Thank you in advance** for any information on this matter.

Kind Regards,

Patrick

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresbytype

Comment: "access plus" means that the browser will be told: "do not fetch a new version of this resource for one month from this moment on". Re your third question, it depends on *when* during those 2 weeks the client comes back. But you can do the math - if it's more than 1 week since they were last there, it'll be the new image.

Comment: Then in the admin panel of my site, I change img1.jpg to img2.jpg.

When I visit back (just a few minutes later) the same page1.html, the displayed image is img2.jpg.

1- So, what is the role of the following code in the .htacces file ?
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month" ?

2- In order to improve the page display speed for visitors who come not very often on my site, I was planning to change :

 - ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month" 
 - to ExpiresByType
 - image/jpeg "access plus 6 months"

Is there any drawback of such change ?


Thank you.

Patrick

Comment: The caching instructions apply to a specific image. If you use a different image (img2.jpg), then of course that one is not going to be cached. The big drawback with long `expires` times is that if you edit the image, the change may not make it to all users in time... then you'd have to change the image name, like you did with img1.jpg and img2.jpg